# How can I make Chrome/Google search on my google data?

Tags: google-drive, google-search, google, google-keep

Google has a lot of places where you can store your data. Drive, Keep, Tasks, Calendar, Gmail, etc.

Sometimes I write a note in Google Keep, sometimes I make a Task, sometimes I make a document on Drive, etc.

It's very annoying to have to go to each individual service to make a search. It's kind of surprising to me that there's no easy way to make Google/Chrome search bar to include results from some of these services.

Is this possible natively? If not, maybe with some workaround/hack?

Comment: Any updates to this question?